# ClassNotFoundException: javax.activation.FileTypeMap when building java springboot mail sender

Tags: java, spring, maven, email

I am trying to learn how to send email in a Java SpringBoot application. I have two classes : EmailSenderService and EmailConfig, respectively in the Service and Configuration packages. When I try to run the project, I am facing the following error : `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.activation.FileTypeMap`

I have tried including several dependencies (including javax.activation, jakarta.activation, etc...) but it does not solve the problem.

The full error trace is :

```
   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'emailSenderService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'javaMailSender': Error creating bean with name 'mailSender' defined in class path resource [com/aventix/api/configuration/EmailConfig.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender]: Factory method 'mailSender' threw exception with message: javax/activation/FileTypeMap
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:712) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:692) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:133) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:481) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1397) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:915) ~[spring-context-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[spring-context-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:432) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
        at com.aventix.api.AventixApplication.main(AventixApplication.java:43) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mailSender' defined in class path resource [com/aventix/api/configuration/EmailConfig.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender]: Factory method 'mailSender' threw exception with message: javax/activation/FileTypeMap
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:657) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:491) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1161) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:561) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1405) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1325) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:709) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender]: Factory method 'mailSender' threw exception with message: javax/activation/FileTypeMap
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:171) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/FileTypeMap
        at com.aventix.api.configuration.EmailConfig.mailSender(EmailConfig.java:16) ~[classes/:na]
        at com.aventix.api.configuration.EmailConfig$$SpringCGLIB$$0.CGLIB$mailSender$0(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
        at com.aventix.api.configuration.EmailConfig$$SpringCGLIB$$2.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:258) ~[spring-core-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at com.aventix.api.configuration.EmailConfig$$SpringCGLIB$$0.mailSender(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:139) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.activation.FileTypeMap
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[na:na]
        ... 45 common frames omitted
```

The classes are as shown below :

EmailSenderService :

```
package com.aventix.api.service;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.mail.MailException;
import org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;

@Service
public class EmailSenderService {

    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

    public void sendSimpleMessage(String to, String subject, String text) {
        try {
            SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
            message.setFrom("bastinus1er@gmail.com");
            message.setTo(to);
            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setText(text);

            javaMailSender.send(message);
        } catch (MailException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
}
```

EmailConfig :

```
package com.aventix.api.configuration;

import java.util.Properties;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl;

@Configuration
public class EmailConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public JavaMailSender mailSender(){
        JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();

        mailSender.setHost("smtp.gmail.com");
        mailSender.setPort(587);
        mailSender.setUsername("******");
        mailSender.setPassword("******");

        return mailSender;
    }

}
```

Comment: try updating your @Bean method name to getJavaMailSender() or javaMailSender()

Comment: @NavneetSingh just tried both names but I get the same error when running the app

Comment: need to see more code then

Comment: All right I understand. What code do you want me to add ?

Comment: nowadays, this problem is usually not caused by _lacking_ the library, but by having _conflicting versions_ of it in the classpath. Try doing `gradle dependencies` and look for one library forcing a bump to other's transitive deps - that's the most usual case here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got around the problem by using the jakarta.mail dependency which worked perfectly.
This solution implies not to use Spring Components but I didnt know how to work my way around with them.

Comment: which dependency you added?